# How to change markup cell font color in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, html, css, fonts, jupyter-notebook

I am using a customized theme for jupyter notebook and the font color for markup cells while it is active and I am typing is black and has barely enough contrast.  I was not able to locate the section in custom.css that dictate the font color. When I inspect the font color, Iit points to codemirror.css, a file that I am not able to locate on my machine. The black fonr is the case for nbextension page. I left some pictures below.

[link](https://github.com/Rhadadi/for_downloading/blob/master/custom.css) to the custom.css file

markup cell:

[image]

nbextension page:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made a bunch of errors/typos in your css file. I suggest running it through a css checker (e.g. [jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator)) before considering your work complete for custom stylesheets.

To expand:

1. in [line 12](https://github.com/Rhadadi/for_downloading/blob/7e0eab4bf5c9a9f994295e820cb9180ba13b7630/custom.css#L12), on the nbextensions page (and indeed the file browser), the text colour is inherited from the `body`, for which it looks like you've attempted to set text colour to (I assume) `#333` (quite dark! maybe something like `#888` would be better?), but in fact you've made a typo, and since `#33` isn't a valid colour code, the rule gets ignored, and text colour remains as the default `#000`. **This is the cause of your problem with the nbextensions page, and the file browser.**
2. in [line 27](https://github.com/Rhadadi/for_downloading/blob/7e0eab4bf5c9a9f994295e820cb9180ba13b7630/custom.css#L27), you've mistakenly added `_area` to the end of a line, resulting in a parse error. This only breaks that line, which is just antialiasing, so not so noticeable.
3. in [line 766](https://github.com/Rhadadi/for_downloading/blob/7e0eab4bf5c9a9f994295e820cb9180ba13b7630/custom.css#L766), padding can't be `none`, it should be `0`. This (setting it `none`/`0`) is perhaps a mistake anyway, as non-disabled menu items still have padding, so it looks weird to remove it completely only for disabled elements.
4. in [line 2495](https://github.com/Rhadadi/for_downloading/blob/7e0eab4bf5c9a9f994295e820cb9180ba13b7630/custom.css#L2495), you've added a second closing bracket. This is a parse error, and as far as I can see, **breaks *everything* in the file following it. This is why your CodeMirror rules are getting ignored.**
5. in [lines 2820-2833](https://github.com/Rhadadi/for_downloading/blob/7e0eab4bf5c9a9f994295e820cb9180ba13b7630/custom.css#L2820-L2833), you've actually included some javascript, which is another parse error. If you need this javascript, consider adding it to a `custom.js` file instead.

Finally, if you're interested in the contents of `CodeMirror.css`, it gets included in the notebook's `main.min.css`, or you can get [the source on GitHub](https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/blob/master/lib/codemirror.css).

Comment: Sounds great! It fixed the font color issue. 
If removed the JavaScript part it does not sure the Latex equations.

I am not sure why I receive error on `text-rendering`, `pointer-events` and `box-flex`.

Comment: The text-rendering, pointer-events and box-flex are non-starters properties I think, so effects may vary across browsers. You could add the JavaScript (minus `<script>` tags) to the custom.js file alongside the CSS one

Answer (score 1):

That's strange, [this line](https://github.com/Rhadadi/for_downloading/blob/7e0eab4bf5c9a9f994295e820cb9180ba13b7630/custom.css#L2496) of your `custom.css` should affect all cells in your notebook.

Perhaps put an `!important` declaration on the colour line so as to override any other styles in place? e.g. change `color: white;` to `color: white !important;`

It's odd that this is only affecting your markdown cells though, as things like brackets and equals signs in your code cells are coloured by the exact same mechanism.

Comment: I added the `!important` declaration but had no effect. The fonts are in white for the code cells or when the markup cell is not active. It is only black when I am writing in a markup cell or when I am in nbextension page.

@jimmyazrael
@Louise Davies